# My WordPress install is not loading the admin styles

Tags: troubleshooting, customization, installation

I'm having this problem where my WordPress install is not loading up any sort of clients scripts or styles, here is what the login form looks like:

[image: WordPress login]

Any ideas on what's going on here? I've reinstalled WordPress manually 3 times now and still nothing and of course, I make sure every single directory and file is included in the install.... I just don't get it.

Comment: So no errors in the console?

Comment: Have you deactivated and plugins and reverted to the default themes and verified they aren't the cause? What errors are in your browsers dev tools console?

Comment: Is this site on your local machine or a live apache server?

Answer (score 2):

There could be any number of problems with your site, so it's really hard to say what the real "problem" is.

I'd suggest first checking out your console for http request errors (see if there are any files not transferring), and also try logging in to see if anything changes.

Based on what you're describing, though, it sounds like you're experiencing the same problems as this other user:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769141/wordpress-admin-not-loading-css-js

Perhaps give that noted fix a shot, and see if that works.

Answer (score -1):

I found in IIS if I start and stop the application pool for this site it resolves this problem.